# Ruby CSV Format Error when reading files with CR / CL / LF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am having a problem reading a .csv file in ruby.

The file format I get for the File is the following:

```
UTF-8 Unicode text, with CR, LF line terminators
```

The Error I get is this:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:607:in `get_row': CSV::IllegalFormatError (CSV::IllegalFormatError)
```

I tried converting the file to

```
UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF, CR line terminators
```

with no change.

Converting to ASCII yields the same results.

Does anyone have experience with this and can offer a solution?

EDIT:
As requested a sample line of the csv

```
670|FirstDataaset|Uppertreet 5|GB|1000|Blue|98764-6547|0374-453534|HU-0973409745|example@example.de
```

It is not the Data, I checked by copy pasting it into a new file and using that for a Test file (not a viable option as a solution, just to confirm the data is not the problem)

Comment: Do you have an example of a few CSV lines? It might also be caused by unclosed quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Since the is a file that you are trying to open, you can do this

```
CSV.foreach(file_path,:col_sep => '|') do |row|
   # whatever you wanna do
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a custom column separator `|` ?

```
string = "670|FirstDataaset|Uppertreet 5|GB|1000|Blue|98764-6547|0374-453534|HU-0973409745|example@example.de"

require 'csv'

p CSV.parse(string, :col_sep => "|")
# => [["670", "FirstDataaset", "Uppertreet 5", "GB", "1000", "Blue", "98764-6547", "0374-453534", "HU-0973409745", "example@example.de"]]
```

Comment: Yes, I have done that. The test I ran with the test file worked with no problems.

Comment: Could please upload a few lines, with the exact same encoding and newlines as your problematic file?